# How to launch video player App using the URL on IOS?

Tags: uri, video-player

On IOS, I am using the following to launch a video URI in a browser. Works great:

```
NSURL *urlVideo = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIxC22Pp1ZI&feature=player_embedded"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: urlVideo];
```

How do I do the similar action, but launch a video App instead.  In Android, I will get a Chooser Dialog if I construct the URI correctly.  Eventually, I will have to implement on both platforms, so I want to be architecturally the same.

Comment: did you find a solution? is there any similar Android chooser dialogs in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use url scheme methods of `UIApplication` objects. The proper method should be `openURL` i believe.

Here is the reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play the video using youtube, you can do it like this :

```
NSURL *urlVideo = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIxC22Pp1ZI"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];

// the last parameter 'jIxC22Pp1ZI' is the video identifier .
```

If you want to launch some other video player, you have to know the custom URL scheme, and pass that to the openURL method.

Comment: Do you know what the custom URL scheme is?  I believe that it should be a value that one has to conform to, so it is common among other sources.